# Socket communication by two children processes in one file

Tags: python, sockets, operating-system, multiprocessing

I am doing an exchange of information that works perfectly well between two files, client and server, however I am having trouble implementing the code into one file with two children processes. As of right now, there is a parent who generates a child which communicates with another client.

I've tried to put all the socket binding into the child process, but to no avail. It only prints the top two lines.
What should I be looking for?

Thanks for all help

server.py (works)

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file
import socket               # Import socket module
import random
import os

g=101 # publicly known
p=103 # publicly known

x= random.randint(1,100) # Alice's random number
y= random.randint(1,100) # Bob's random number

aliceSends = (p**x)%g
bobComputes = (aliceSends**y)%g
bobSends = (p**y)%g

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection up to 5.

print 'Qsocket: Using sockets for IPC'
print 'Diffie-Hellman Parameters p=103 and g=101'
print 'Parent: pid= ',os.getpid(),'\n'

while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Alice Accepted connection from Bob\n'

   if os.fork() == 0:
      #sends first message
      print 'Alice: pid= ',os.getpid(), ', my Parent pid= ',os.getppid()
      print 'Alice Random Secret: ' + str(x)
      print 'Alice Public T: ' + str(aliceSends)
      print 'Alice send to Bob its Public T: ',aliceSends,'\n'
      c.send(str(aliceSends))

      #receieves message
      bobSends = int(c.recv(1024))

      print '<< Alice Got Bob Public T: ',str(bobSends)
      aliceComputes = (bobSends**x)%g
      print 'Alice-to-Bob Shared Secret: << (' + str(aliceComputes) + ') >>'

   c.close()                # Close the connection

print 'Parent: Alice and Bob exited'
```

client.py (works)

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file
import socket               # Import socket module
import random
import os

g=101 # publicly known
p=103 # publicly known

y= random.randint(1,100) # Bob's random number

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
#receieves first message
print 'Bob: Connected to Alice\n'
print 'Bob: pid= ',os.getpid()
print 'Bob Random Secret: ' + str(y)
bobSends = (p**y)%g
print 'Bob Public T: ' + str(bobSends),'\n'

aliceSends = int(s.recv(1024))
bobComputes = str((aliceSends**y)%g)

print '>> Bob Got Alice Public T: ',str(aliceSends)
print 'Bob-to-Alice Shared Secret: << (' + str(bobComputes) +') >>'
print 'Bob send to Alice its Public T: ',bobSends


#sends message back
s.send(str(bobSends))
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

Here is the compacted code from above similar to what I want it to do, but it's hanging up on the server call and never gets to the client:
cliserv.py (fixed)

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file
import socket               # Import socket module
import random
import os

g=101 # publicly known
p=103 # publicly known

x= random.randint(1,100) # Alice's random number
y= random.randint(1,100) # Bob's random number

aliceSends = (p**x)%g
bobComputes = (aliceSends**y)%g
bobSends = (p**y)%g

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = random.randint(0,65500)                # Reserve a port for your service.

print 'Qsocket: Using sockets for IPC'
print 'Diffie-Hellman Parameters p=103 and g=101'
print 'Parent: pid= ',os.getpid(),'\n'

if os.fork() == 0:
   s = socket.socket()
   s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
   s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection up to 5.
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.

   print 'Alice Accepted connection from Bob\n'

   #sends first message
   print 'Alice: pid= ',os.getpid(), ', my Parent pid= ',os.getppid()
   print 'Alice Random Secret: ' + str(x)
   print 'Alice Public T: ' + str(aliceSends)
   print 'Alice send to Bob its Public T: ',aliceSends,'\n'
   c.send(str(aliceSends))

   #receieves message 'thanks for thanking'
   bobSends = int(c.recv(1024))

   print '<< Alice Got Bob Public T: ',str(bobSends)
   aliceComputes = (bobSends**x)%g
   print 'Alice-to-Bob Shared Secret: << (' + str(aliceComputes) + ') >>'
   c.close()                # Close the connection
elif os.fork() ==0:
   g=101 # publicly known
   p=103 # publicly known

   s = socket.socket()
   s.connect((host, port))
   #receieves first message
   print 'Bob: Connected to Alice\n'
   print 'Bob: pid= ',os.getpid()
   print 'Bob Random Secret: ' + str(y)
   bobSends = (p**y)%g
   print 'Bob Public T: ' + str(bobSends),'\n'

   aliceSends = int(s.recv(1024))
   bobComputes = str((aliceSends**y)%g)

   print '>> Bob Got Alice Public T: ',str(aliceSends)
   print 'Bob-to-Alice Shared Secret: << (' + str(bobComputes) +') >>'
   print 'Bob send to Alice its Public T: ',bobSends


   #sends message back
   s.send(str(bobSends))
   s.close                     # Close the socket when done
else:
   #parent
   os.wait()
   # one child has exited
   os.wait()
   # both children have exited
   print 'Parent: Alice and Bob exited'
```

The output should look like:

```
Qsocket: Using sockets for IPC
Diffie-Hellman Parameters p=103 and g=101
Parent: pid=  5462
Alice: pid=  5463  my Parent pid=  5462 

Alice Random Secret: 64
Alice Public T:  79
Alice send to Bob its Public T:  79 

Bob: pid=  5464  my Parent pid=  5462 

Bob Random Secret: 85
Bob Public T: 62

>> Bob Got Alice Public T:  79
Bob-to-Alice Shared Secret: << (36) >>
Bob send to Alice its Public T:  62 

<< Alice Got Bob Public T:  62
Alice-to-Bob Shared Secret: <<(36)>>

Parent: Alice Exited
Parent: Bob Exited
```

Edit: Updated code so all three versions work.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Your code appears to work fine for me, in that the client connects to the server, and both compute the same shared secret.  But +1 for a well-written [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield My code works, but I essentially need to truncate into one file with two children, Alice and Bob, and not a separate client and server file, all using sockets. The posted code is my current code.

And thank you for the +1. :)

Comment: Why not just put a `if fork() == 0: (code from server.py); else: (code from client.py)` at the start of your file?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I updated my code above with something similar, but I am getting absolutely no output from either. What is it about a process in another file that allows a connection but not a fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my answer from http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1ywkut/python_socket_communication_by_two_children/.

The steps to fix the code are.

1. Get rid of the while loop. It's not necessary, and having forks inside the while loop can cause fork bombs.
2. Server and client processes should use separate sockets and network logic. However, they should use the same port number.
3. Parent process should call `os.wait` twice at the end to make sure both child processes have exited.